# Unknown number instead of anonymous number

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, caller-id

I've got a question, sometimes when the Caller ID is hidden, it will show up on my lock screen as "Anonymous". But recently, I've noticed something, there is a distinction between Anonymous and "Unknown", when missing a call.

Who can tell me what "unknown number" means, I suppose a caller either has the number hidden (anonymous) or shown (just the number that shows up, or a contact)? I also received a voicemail from the unknown number, which is just a 3 second message with a computer voice.

Who can clear this up for me?

Answer (score 1):

Unknown means the carrier didn't send a CID response.  Anonymous means they populated it with the word 'Anonymous'.

Comment: Can I assume then that if the carrier doesn't send a CID it is most likely to be something like fake calls?

Comment: Of course not.  There are any number of legitimate reasons to block CID.